# nodejs forms module: how to add class to a field

Tags: forms, class, node.js

I am trying to use forms module https://github.com/caolan/forms . I could easily get the forms created without any issues. But I am just wondering how do you add a new class name to the existing field. The documentation talks about the overriding the id. But I could not find a way to add a new class to the tag.

tried the following..but it wont work!

```
  username: fields.string({
    required: true,
    label: 'So What',
    classes: ['classtest']
    }),
```

There is a attribute called widget (which in turn has attribute 'classes') for field. But could not get it working either. This is what I tried. Which also failed.

```
username: fields.string({
required: true,
label: 'So What',
widget: {
  classes: 'testclass'
}
}),
```

Any help in this regard would help. Ultimately i am trying to style the forms with bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the module doesn't allow classes anywhere except at the widget level.  Use the following to apply classes to the input box (ie. widget).

```
username: fields.string({
    required: true,
    label: 'So What',
    widget: forms.widgets.text({
        classes: ['testclass']
    })
})
```

The current form module API provides no way to extend the classes that are placed on the surrounding div element.  Here is a bit of stack trace as to how I found it out:

1. [lib/fields.js#L68](https://github.com/caolan/forms/blob/master/lib/fields.js#L68) calls [forms.render.div](https://github.com/caolan/forms/blob/master/lib/render.js#L20)
2. [forms.render.div](https://github.com/caolan/forms/blob/master/lib/render.js#L20) calls [field.classes().join(' ')](https://github.com/caolan/forms/blob/master/lib/render.js#L5)
3. [field.classes()](https://github.com/caolan/forms/blob/master/lib/fields.js#L61) returns a rigid array of classes.  The only options are field, error, and required.